# Nikon D5100 shutter button not working

Tags: nikon, shutter

I'm having problems with my Nikon D5100, generally when I first pick it up it will work fine for 3, maybe 4, shots then the button just stops working, I press it but nothing happens. If I change to the screen view mode (instead of looking through the view finder) it generally works again but is very slow to respond. Any ideas? Note: It doesn't always work at first sometimes it's not working from the off.

Comment: The first of all I would try resetting to factory settings.

Comment: The fact that it works with live view mode suggests to me that it's a focus issue. That's because the two modes use an entirely different technology for focusing. You don't happen to be running into [this problem](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12185/why-cant-my-slr-autofocus-on-certain-parts-of-a-scene), do you?

Comment: Does the problem persist if you select manual focus?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I will try that tonight.

Comment: How do I reset factory settings, I did have a go at that but I'm sure I did it right?

Comment: I experienced that a lot with my Sony Alpha. It turned out that it happened when I was using the telephoto lens, with autofocus, and trying to photograph an object (usually a butterfly) that was too close. If I stepped back a few inches, the button worked again. I was ready to take the camera back to the store until I realized what was happening. That's of course not necessarily what's going on with your camera, but hey, you asked for "any ideas".

Answer (score 3):

Try switching to manual focus mode (MF switch on your lens). If the problem solved - your camera has troubles focusing. The reasons might be:

- Insufficient light
- Lens AF problem (try a different lens to see if the problem remains)
- Body AF problem (contact service)

If MF didn't solve the problem:
Try a different memory card. After you snap a batch of photos, they are queued to be stored to a memory card. This takes time. Cheaper cards are slower. Plus, the queue isn't infinite - depending on your camera, it can hold no more than, let's say, five shots.

Comment: Memory card could also be close to failing.